# Website won't display on IE, but source code is viewable

Tags: javascript, css, debugging, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My website doesn't seem to display any element or content when viewed on IE even though source code is viewable, but on firefox and chrome it loads fine. What is up???

http://uber-upload.com

I don't remember ever trying to load my website with IE, so i can't confirm if it ever has worked with IE. Please help me debug =/. WADAFA!??! Thanks for your help

Comment: You just might get slashdotted for posting that url

Comment: It also doesnt show in my opera browser....  Switching to firefox now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your xml prolog syntax might be causing this.

I believe it should be like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

see: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Comment: I just tested the code in Opera using DragonFly, and I found that it's interpreting the <xml> tag as node within the body... by removing the tag, or changing it to <?xml> the page showed up properly.

Comment: OMFG!!!! I only removed the ? in the ?xml because my php was interpreting it as well... php, and it isnt. Thanks!

Comment: So ya, solution = remove the whole thing altogether.

Answer (score 6):

Your website is probably confusing the buggery out of IE - the HTML validator found many errors. [Click here](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fuber-upload.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Start by ensuring your document is valid XHTML (since that's what you're declaring in your doctype). Then we'll go from there.

Comment: +1, I've seen similar problems in IE if sent invalid markup. Other browsers typically have no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a ? to the XML tag.

```
<xml version="1.0">
<!DOCTYPE html .....>
```

into

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<!DOCTYPE html ...>
```

But you do want to validate your site: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: A few things --

1: The xml prolog actually should go _above_ the doctype for correct rendering in IE6.
2: The xml prolog, as written, is incorrect (it requires a question mark right after its open bracket
3: The doctype declaration should not be html if using the xml prolog; rather, it should declare which flavor of xhtml it is.  That is, if it's the author's intent to actually use xhtml, which, it's not really clear from the source code if that's what he intended.

Comment: I just copy and pasted the DOCTYPE tag, which I why I put in the ....s. Otherwise, I've fixed my answer

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens to me when I accidentally close a `<script>` tag in an XML way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js" />
```

The following does work for IE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js">
</script>
```

This doesn't appear to be what you've done, but I wanted to add this answer anyway because it's a common reason for this problem to appear.

Comment: I'm always falling for that doosie too.